# WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found

Tags: java, database, api

I'm trying to call another API and it gives me WebClientResponseException

```
2021-11-03 19:54:55.762 [5a2a9625f3c7ff19/5a2a9625f3c7ff19] ERROR
        {FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} 23556 [ctor-http-nio-4] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger                 
        {cyan} : onError(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST http://localhost:8082/v1/persons/getAllIds)
2021-11-03 19:54:55.788 [5a2a9625f3c7ff19/5a2a9625f3c7ff19] ERROR
        {FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} 23556 [ctor-http-nio-4] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger                 
        {cyan} : 

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST http://localhost:8082/v1/persons/getAllIds
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:185)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 404 from POST http://localhost:8082/v1/persons/getAllIds [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:185)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:209)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)
```

```
@Override
public Flux<Person> getByIds(List<String> ids) {
    log.info("getIds :  {}",ids);
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(config.getIdURL()).build())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(Mono.just(ids), List.class)
            .header(geConstant.X_APP_ID_KEY, geConstant.X_APP_ID_VALUE)
            .header(geConstant.X_API_KEY_KEY, geConstant.X_API_KEY_VALUE)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Person.class)
            .log("Find ids : " + ids)
            .retryBackoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
}
```

Comment: A `404` error means that a resource can't be found at the URL. Have you confirmed that you can `POST http://localhost:8082/v1/persons/getAllIds` using a tool like Postman?

Comment: isnt that supposed to be get and not POST? you are getting stuff and not posting

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL was not found at
(POST) http://localhost:8082/v1/persons/getAllIds
I recommend to make sure that you have that endpoint running and to
hit it with Postman.